# Disable WCF Help page not working

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to disable the help page for WCF service.  It is the file which ends with Service.svc/help. As recommended elsewhere I added the following to my web.config

```
<serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="false" httpsHelpPageEnabled="false"/>
```

Yet I can view the help page. Is there some other setting that I should change?

Comment: What did you exactly add to your web.config?

Comment: I added the following to my web.config <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="false" httpsHelpPageEnabled="false"/> under ServiceBehavior tag

Answer (score 3):

You may want to checkout: [WCF help page - how to disable or change the displayed URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850735/wcf-help-page-how-to-disable-or-change-the-displayed-url)

```
`<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="MyNamespace.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="NoHelpPageBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyNamespace.IMyContract" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="NoHelpPageBehavior">
      <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="false" httpsHelpPageEnabled="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```